# When to apply Principal Component Analysis PCA

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

When do I apply **PCA**, is it after preprocessing (i.e removing null values, encoding etc.,) the entire dataset or before? After I've completely preprocessed my dataset,

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
x_train[:,0:14] = sc.fit_transform(x_train[:,0:14])
x_test[:,0:14] = sc.transform(x_test[:,0:14])
```

I'm left with the shape, 113126x91

Comment: Are you removing features the analysis should find, or features it should ignore?

Comment: PCA is used to find the most relevant features that describes the variance of the data. Ex: Lets say you have 100 attributes. But some of them are already dependent to each other, and using 30 attributes is enough to explain %95 of what data actually means (variance). On the light of this information, it would be better to implement PCA after scaling. So that, PCA would not be biased because of having different scales in attributes. 

Please check: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_scaling_importance.html

Comment: Sorry if my q doesn't make any sense but I would like to know if we need to perform it after pre processing or before pre processing the data.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 2):

Applying PCA is better on scaled data because you won't face the Large vs. Tiny problem between features.

Large vs. Tiny problem means that the variance of features would be different. for example, in a dataset, one feature has a range (-5, +5) and another lies in the range of (-10000, +10000). Features with larger values can dominate the process.

PCA is a dimensionality reduction technique used to reduce the dimensionality of large data sets by transforming a large collection of variables into a smaller one that still contains most of the information in the large group. To reduce dimensions, PCA takes eigenvectors with higher eigenvalues and map your data points to those vectors; hence dimensionality is reduced.

Let me give you an example of how applying PCA after scaling will be helpful.

Let me import some valuable things that we will be using for this example.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale, normalize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# For reproducibility 
np.random.seed(123)
```

Let me make a dummy data set on which we will see the effect of applying PCA before and after scaling.

```
rows = 100
features = 7

X = np.random.normal(size=[rows, features])
X = np.append(X, 3*np.random.choice(2, size = [rows,1]), axis = 1)
```

A dummy dataset is created in variable X having 100 examples and 7 features. Now lets apply PCA on it without scaling and plot the data.

```
pca = PCA(2)
low_x = pca.fit_transform(X)
plt.scatter(low_x[:,0], low_x[:,1])
```

Here is a plot of data after reducing the number of features from 7 to 2 without scaling the dataset. You can see that data points are very near and messy. One feature has a higher variance than the other. For further processing or modeling, this will affect the results.

[image]

Let's apply feature scaling first and then apply PCA to the dataset.

```
X_normalized = normalize(X)
pca = PCA(2)
low_x = pca.fit_transform(X_noramlized)
plt.scatter(low_x[:,0], low_x[:,1])
```

In the following plot, the data is clear and scattered. There is no big difference between the variance of both features.

[image]

Hence, it is always better to apply normalization before applying PCA to a dataset.

But always remember one thing, Data science is mostly hit and try for developers. Try this if it doesn't help your results, you can always try a different way.